# to find new location of files that are moved to different location - Java

Tags: java, header-files

I have a folder of header files in older version of our application.
There are many header files directly inside that folder and also inside many subfolders... Now we are going to use a newer version of the application in which the header files path are present in different subfolders than they used to be before. I want to write a java program(preferably), that gives me a one to one mapping of the old path and the new path of the headers. I have the root directory of header files in both the version... i want to find the differences in header file path with respect to the root directories.

Header files Root Directory of Old Version: **Root1**

Header Files Root Directory of New Version: **Root2**

Under Root1 consider there are three sub folders: **Folder1, Folder2, Folder3**

Under Root2 consider there are three sub folders: **Folder1, Folder2, Folder3**

Under Root1/Folder1 there were three files: **File1,File2,File3**

```
Root1/Folder1/File1,
Root1/Folder1/File2,
Root1/Folder1/File3.
```

Now in new version these files are like:

```
Root2/Folder1/File1,
Root2/Folder2/File3,
Root2/Folder3/File2.
```

The files are restructured.
I want to write a program to find out the new version path for these files by scanning both the root folders:

Required output:

```
Root1/Folder1/File1 = Root2/Folder1/File1
Root1/Folder1/File2 = Root2/Folder3/File2
Root1/Folder1/File3 = Root2/Folder2/File3.
```

Sorry if I am not clear. SO is a reference site if we are facing any problem in programming. I am stuck with this running out of ideas for this logic. Kindly Help.

**EDIT 1:**

sorry for the delay.. the file names are same in both the versions. let me tell the requirement. throughout the project, hundreds of header files are included referring to old version... its c and cpp based code. now we need to change in code all the include statements according to new header paths. so manually changing one by one searching through the windows explorer is tedious. it doesn't matter if the header files have changed. new function definitions might have been added in the new version. but we need to include the same header file.

this program might save a lot of manual hours. Thanks :)

Comment: No, you are not clear. What features are available that would allow a program to generate the mapping you want? Are the files identical except for their names? Something else perhaps?

Comment: Before you can write any code you must define an exact, unambiguous mapping between each old path/filename and the new path/filename.  I.e., for every old name there must be an algorithm that can determine unambiguously where the file is in the new scheme.  If you cannot do this based on solely the path and name you will probably need to examine the file contents, or use a file digest to determine where files are moved to.  If there's no unique mapping and also file contents have changed, you may be out of luck.

Comment: In any event, this question is completely off-topic for SO as it stands.

Comment: @JimGarrison Not if OP supplies some code showing his efforts up to now.

Comment: @Mohamed - Do *file* names remain the same across all dictionary rearrangements? Your statement "The files are restructured" is confusing.

Comment: It's funny that this was put on hold for being "unclear" **after** OP had clarified the question and accepted an answer.

Comment: they put on hold after i clarified with an Edit.. but I accepted the answer after they put on Hold... :)

Comment: I feel nowadays SO is becoming more and more like CodeRanch, too much restrictions in order to standardize it. People may hesitate to ask a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This assumes that file names do not change during the migration from one directory tree into the other one.**

This is quick and dirty and lacks all sanity checks and error handling, but it illustrates the main point: recursive descent into a directory to collect the files to collect a mapping of file names to paths. The comp method just takes the names from the first directory tree and displays path names from both trees.

```
public void find( File root, Map<String, String> map ){
    File[] entries = root.listFiles();
    for( File file: entries ){
        if( file.isDirectory() ){
            find( file, map );
        } else {
            map.put( file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath() );
        }
    }
}

public void comp( File root1, File root2 ){
    Map<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    find( root1, map1 );
    Map<String,String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    find( root2, map2 );
    for( String name1: map1.keySet() ){
        String path1 = map1.get( name1 );
        String path2 = map2.get( name1 );
        System.out.println( name1 + ": " + path1 + "->" + path2 ); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I am giving it a try.

Comment: Ah, the background... Probably the include statements contain relative paths and these need to be fixed. - If you trim the paths in the map you can generate sed statements from that printout. Will indeed save some time.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming they're named the same,

You can:

```
File oldH = "/";
For (path:oldH) {
 // Map<fname,dir> odb=path;
File newH = "/new/";
For (path:newH)
 // Map<fname,dir> ndb=path;
Array newarray[]=ndb.size();
While(odb.hasNext()) {
    While (ndb.hasNext()) {
    If (odb.fname.next()==ndb.fname.next()) {
        newarray[i][0]= odb.path;
        newarray[i][1]= ndb.path;
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
```

It's just pseudocode, but I hope that helps.

Comment: I've never seen anything more "pseudo" than this.

Comment: Yea, well, thanks :-)

Comment: I am pretty that was not meant as compliment as this does not even make logical sense in that there are things referenced that are not even declared, without even mentioning this make no logical sense